# Использование команд U и A при дизассемблировании

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с двумя проблемами. Только начал проходить работу с машинным кодом. Все делал пошагово, как и было в указаниях методических.

Вообщем была создана программа. Пользуясь командной строкой запустил ее `debug program.COM`. С помощью отладчика просмотреть исходную программу: `-U`. Потом трассировал ее как в задании. 
И вот здесь вопросы, идут последовательно:

1. с помощью команды `U` узнать адрес 6 команды MOV AX, 0001?
2. а потом с помощью команды `A` заменить команду MOV AX, 0001 командой?
   MOV AX, 0002.

Это первая работа с подобными кодами, в интернете мне подходящего ответа найти не смог, пожалуйста, подскажите что следует ввести.

Comment: Говорю сразу, я пробовал сам это сделать, но ничего не вышло. методические указания довольно бесполезны, а в интернете не находит так, как  даже не могу полноценно сформулировать вопрос

Comment: Не привыкайте вы к этому debug, его давно нигде нет. Какой-нибудь IDA себе лучше поставьте.

Comment: @vp_arth, вероятно вы правы, но таково задание. Могу ли я попросить вас о помощи, раз уж вы откликнулись?

Comment: похоже меня бросили

Comment: @MuscledBoy боюсь что все, кто может откликнуться, эти отходы динозавра если и знали, то давно забыли подробности как абсолютно бесполезные ненужности :)

Comment: @PinkTux, по правде говоря, мне от этого не легче. Если я вас правильно понимаю, сейчас на этот вопрос мне никто не даст ответа?

Comment: На какой вопрос-то?

Comment: @PinkTux, они пронумерованы

Comment: Вопросы - это то, что заканчивается `?`. В чём они у вас заключаются? Как найти на клавиатуре кнопки `U` и `A`?

Comment: @PinkTux, их я нашел, а вот синтаксис команды нет, его и спрашиваю. например со вторым вопросом: `-A (address)` , `Enter` , `new command` или как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cходил в [Википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug).
И ещё [вот сюда](http://www.celitel.info/klad/nhelp/helpbat.php?dcmd=debug).

> -U [диапазон] Команда преобразования кода в инструкции ассемблера. Сокращённо от слова Unassemble.

```
Параметр диапазон используется в подкомандах debug для задания диапазона памяти.  
Параметр диапазон можно задать в одном из следующих форматов: 
 - начальный адрес и конечный адрес  
 - начальный адрес и длина (обозначаемая l) диапазона.  
Например, оба следующих выражения задают диапазон из 16 байтов, начинающийся с адреса CS:100:

cs:100 10f
cs:100 l 10
```

> -A [адрес] Преобразования инструкции ассемблера в машинный код. Сокращённо от слова Assemble.

```
Параметр адрес  
Задает адрес, по которому записаны инструкции на языке ассемблер.  
Параметр адрес принимает шестнадцатеричные значения без знака h.
```

Пример:

```
-U [Нажать Enter]
 1814:0100 ADD [BX+SI],AL 
 1814:0102 XOR AL,00

-A 1814:0102[Нажать Enter]
1814:0102 MOV AX,0009 [Нажать Enter]
```

Comment: я вводил `-U`,это список всех команд, а мне надо с помощью этого самого U узнать адрес команды MOV AX, 0001. А потом с помощью A заменить команду MOV AX, 0001 командой MOV AX, 0002. Извините, если это оно и есть, просто мозги не варят уже. Пол дня пытаюсь разобраться и ни как. Так что, если да, то напишите.

Comment: Вводите -U, ищете глазами строчку с нужной вам командой, слева от неё видите адрес

Comment: Если я верно помню, после -А можно ввести этот адрес

Comment: то есть на вашем примере  `-A 1814:0100 `, нажать Enter, и ввести `MOV AX, 0002`? еще раз не обижайтесь, если нет. Я только учусь.

Comment: Он же интерактивный, там всё видно. Нет не `1814:0100` - это точка входа в .com, ищите нужный адрес.

Comment: вы имеете в виду `B81200` ? такого типа адрес? в hex?